# Get latest AWS S3 folder when both folder and files inside folder created at same time boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

im trying to get latest folder in a given s3 prefix using below code

For ex:

s3a://mybucket/data/timestamp=20180612165132/part1.parquete
s3a://mybucket/data/timestamp=20180612165132/part2.parquete
s3a://mybucket/data/timestamp=20180613165132/part1.parquete
s3a://mybucket/data/timestamp=20180614165132/part1.parquete
s3a://mybucket/data/timestamp=20180615165132/part1.parquete

I need to find the latest timestamp folder under data folder..

```
  keys = []
  oldest = None

  kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Prefix': key}
  while True:
      resp = get_conn().list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
      for obj in resp['Contents']:
          keys.append({'Key': obj['Key'], 'LastModified': obj['LastModified']})

      try:
          kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
      except KeyError:
          break

  logger.info("Got {0} keys".format(len(keys)))

  for key in keys:
      oldest = key['LastModified'] if oldest is None or key['LastModified'] < oldest else oldest

  return oldest
```

The issue is i have 100 of files under each timestamp folder ,in the above im getting timestamp of each file created finding the oldest file under each timestamp folder to know the timestamp folder creation date

Im using this code as s3 treats this whole thing as 1 object

```
 s3a://mybucket/data/timestamp=20180612165132/part1.parquete
```

there is no way im able to get the LastModifiedDate of the timestamp folder

And this is very expensive i feel as there can be hundreds of timestamp folders and each folder has 100 of files..

Is there any best way to achieve this?

Comment: Side-node: Folders don't actually exist in Amazon S3. They "appear" to be there, but objects can be created in any path and, once deleted, the 'folder' disappears. Some systems create zero-length files with the same name as the folder to force the folder to 'appear'. However, the modification date on such a file would not represent the modification date of the contents of the folder (since the folder doesn't exist!).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i do understand there is no concept of folders everything is object but how to find latest timestamp folder among the list of s3 locations i mentioned above? Also if i create timestamp folder and the files inside the folder seperately ,folder and files are treated as seperate objects and im able to get LastModifiedDate on the timestamp folder but when i create them at same time there is no other way for me other than above

Comment: Are you referring to the timestamp that is part of the name of the path, or are you looking for a magical timestamp at the folder level that updates whenever the contents of the "folder" is changed?

Comment: im referring to the timestamp that is part of the name of the path,,but in short i want to know the folder which is created latest among all the timestamp folders,as in my case there is no content update inside the folder its just created once along with the content

Comment: @JohnRotenstein     To add more context one of my Spark apps creates this folder structure in S3 and i have another application which needs to get latest data produced by the spark app.Lemme know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

As Josh says in the comments: there are no directories, so no directory timestamp.

The tools just make them up, such as in [S3AFileStatus](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileStatus.java#L54).

Some ideas

1. if the "folders" have their timestamp in the name, do a list of the parent path with suffix "/" ^ look for the entry whose timestamp is highest.
2. have each query write some index file in the base dir, containing a string of their directory. load that, you get the name of the latest file. Later jobs will overwrite. Warning: S3 overwrite consistency means you *may* get the older version, at least for a brief period (seconds, tens of seconds, at worst (usually))

option #2 would probably be fastest